# Callback to Android application when system panel shown

Tags: android, callback, system, panel

I'm running my test applications on HTC One X stock 4.0.3 ROM.

When I long press "Power" I have a system panel "Phone Options" where I can select "Power off", "Airplane mode" or "Restart". 
Actually this is what we have with any Android phone, sort of.

The problem here that my activity doesn't receive "onPause" callback. And I cannot stop threads and to other pre-stop staff.

Is it possible to have a callback when any system panel (de)activated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A broadcast ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS will be thrown just before any system dialog pops up. So you can register a reciever for this intent using

```
registerReceiver(reciever, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
```

This intent has a flag FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY, so you cannot recieve this broadcast if you register using Manifest file. So you will have to use registerReciever. This might be thrown in other cases too. This can be used only when activation of system dialog, not sure about deactivation

Comment: Yep, it works when the dialog is up. To catch the dialog off it some other method required.

Comment: Another solution (much better in my case) is to hook onWindowFocusChanged in my activity and decide what to do.

Comment: I was wrong. I have to combine Nandeesh's approach and "onWindowFocusChanged" in Activity.